# Flex 3 and Spring 4 Integration POM Dependencies

Tags: apache-flex, spring, flex4, blazeds

What are the maven dependencies in order to completely download all the Spring 3 and Flex 4 files required for the Spring Blaze Integration project?

Currently I am getting an exception that this class is not found:

```
flex.messaging.​AbstractFlexSessionProvider
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here are the dependencies you'll need:

```
<!--  jms -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
            <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Dependencies for Spring Flex Remoting -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.flex</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-flex</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.flex.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.adobe.flex.framework</groupId>
        <artifactId>flex-framework</artifactId>
        <version>${flex.sdk.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
         <exclusions> 
           <exclusion> 
            <groupId>com.adobe.flex.framework</groupId> 
            <artifactId>playerglobal</artifactId> 
           </exclusion> 
         </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency> 
          <groupId>com.adobe.flex.framework</groupId> 
          <artifactId>playerglobal</artifactId> 
          <version>${flex.sdk.version}</version>
          <classifier>10.1</classifier>
          <type>swc</type> 
     </dependency>
```